# NameError undefined in Python function

Tags: python, function, undefined

I want to calculate the area under a curve with an integral (Riemann). I wrote some code but it's giving me problems when I run it: `NameError: name 'y' is not defined`.

This is the code:

```
from math import *

def f(x):
   return y**2

def integral (A, B, Rectangulos):
    ancho = (float(B) - float(A)) / Rectangulos
    suma = 0
    for i in range(Rectangulos):
       altura = f(A + i * ancho)
       area = altura * ancho
       suma = suma + area
    return suma

A = int(input("Asigna el valor de A:  "))
B = int(input("Asigna el valor de B:  "))

Rectangulos = int(input("Indique la cantidad de rectangulos que desea utilizar \n (Recuerde que mientras mayor sea la densidad, el valor final sera mas cercano al valor deseado):  "))

print ("El valor aproximado de esta integral es ", integral(A,B,Rectangulos))
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Change `y` to `x` in the return statement of the function `f`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is `y`? It is undefined, and that is why you are getting that error. You wanted to write:

```
def f(x):
   return x**2
```

Comment: y**2 is the function the professor is asking me to determinate

Comment: I know you meant to do y = A + i * ancho and then calculate f(y). It will work, change your code to what I showed.

Comment: @LuisTrujillo could well be, but it is not in scope in `f`.

Comment: hes asking literally for f(x,y) = y ^ 2 (Square)

Comment: You should review functions... Anyway my answer is correct, try it! I might be able to expand on it later on.

Comment: @LuisTrujillo there is a big difference between mathematics and code. `y` is _not_ in scope in `f`, and indeed not even defined anywhere! Also, `f(x, y) = y^2` is not a function of x (that is, `x` is completely redundant).